# ros on lynxmotion AL5D

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Sorry for my poor English.
I have a project about lynx AL5D, a robotic arm. My teacher recommanded me to use ROS. I have read the tutorials, but I still have no idea about the project. The tutorials talk a lot about the service, topics, launch files... but it doesn't talk about how to make my robotic arm move.

I just want to use the keyboard to control the robotic arm to turn left right. I will appricate if you can give me some suggestions

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55233/ros-on-lynxmotion-al5d/) by [lxxdn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4207/lxxdn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) on 2015-01-25**:
Hello! to move the arm you need a driver. In the case of lynxmotion arms they come with serial RS232 based interface. The way to move the arm is by sending 3 bytes to the board. I have a robot with lynmotion arm l6ac-kt, check the code here!

https://github.com/oscar-lima/little_bas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a driver for the arm which is found [here](https://github.com/smd-ros-devel/lynxmotion_ssc32).  You would need to publish the desired joint angles to make the arm move.  The driver takes care of the communication between your machine and the ssc32.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0